# TableView change all the rows when I try to edit one column value in javafx

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I have a `TableView` that has its items property bound to a class `Group`'s  `applications` property which is declared as :

```
ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Application>> applications = new SimpleObjectProperty();
```

it is initialised as :

```
applications.set(new FXCollections.observableArrayList<Application>());
applications.get().add(new Application());
applications.get().add(new Application());
```

The class `Application` class contains some properties and another class `Customer` declared and initialised as :

```
ObjectProperty<Customer> customer = SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Customer());
```

Now there are four columns in the tableView that are editable they are 'ApplicationNo', 'ApplicationDate', 'CustomerId' and 'CustomerName'. The first 2 column's cell value factory is set to `Application` class's `applicationNo` and `applicationDate` properties. and the last 2 column's cell value factory are set to the `Application` class's `customer` property's `customerId` and `customerName` properties. All the four columns are editable with combobox control that are populated with values from the database.

In addition to the above stated table view, I have a form in the FXML consisting of fields that are there in the `Application` class and the `Customer` class. This form is disabled when no table row is selected and is enabled with the values of the `Application` instance, when any of the table view row is selected.

Now my problem is when I select any row and edit the values in the form or in the table, all the row attain the new value that I enter.

I am not uploading the code because it is very lengthy.

**the code for `updateItem` method of table cell editor**

```
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (control != null) {
                updateControl();
            }
            setGraphic(control);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        } else {
            setText(getItemText());
            setGraphic(null);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
    }
```

Code for cell factory and cell value factory of column `applicationNo`

```
    applicationNo.setCellValueFactory(
            new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<GroupRow, ApplicationModel>, ObservableValue<ApplicationModel>>() {
//GroupRow is the object that contains the Application object
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<ApplicationModel> call(CellDataFeatures<GroupRow, ApplicationModel> param) {
                    return param.getValue().getApplicationProperty();
                }
            });
    applicationNo.setCellFactory(
            new Callback<TableColumn<GroupRow, ApplicationModel>, TableCell<GroupRow, ApplicationModel>>() {

                @Override
                public TableCell<GroupRow, ApplicationModel> call(TableColumn<GroupRow, ApplicationModel> param) {
                    return new ApplicationTableCellEditor();
//ApplicationTableCellEditor is custom TableCell
                }
            });
    applicationNo.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<GroupRow, ApplicationModel>>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<GroupRow, ApplicationModel> event) {
            event.getRowValue().setApplication(event.getNewValue());
            tableChanged();
            applicationChanged(event.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you override the `setItem` or `updateItem` of your table cell? Can you provide at least the parts setting cell factories and cell value factories?

Comment: @sillyfly I did override the `updateItem` in the table cell. I have uploaded the details of the `updateItem` method

Comment: @sillyfly I have added the code for cell factory and cellvaluefactory for the column `applicationNo`

Comment: Have you confirmed that the different `GroupRow` objects are not all being set to the same `Application` object somewhere? Perhaps in your `applicationChanged()` call in `setOnEditCommit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have figured out the actual problem and its solution. For changing Row selection I was using :

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(.....);
```

This actually when I selected the 2nd row after selecting the first row as both the rows contained and equal instance of `Application` resulting in `row1.equals(row2)` which in turn did not allow the above listener to fire. So, The unbinding of values never happened and result that the controls remained bound to both the rows.

So as a solution I changed the above to:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(......);
```

Here this fired every time I selected a different row thereby unbinding the controls and the properties of the previous row and binding the controls to the properties of the new row. This solved my problem. I would request If any one has any other suggestions please post the answer.